# Laravel whereHas() / orWherehas() with where('id', '!=', $id) closure doesn't seem to work on one-to-many relation?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I want to query all the entries of an one-to-many relation not already associated with the given resource.

In this case I have the Basket model containing a Country relation

```
public function country()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Country::class);
}
```

And vice-versa

```
public function baskets()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Basket::class);
}
```

The table `baskets` has the required column `country_id`

To query all Countries for a Basket with id 1, except for the one Country already attached to it, I would expect to use the following query:

```
$countries = Country::whereDoesntHave('baskets')
    ->orWherehas('baskets', function($query) {
        $query->where('id', '!=', 1);
    })->get()
```

But this is giving me all Countries in the table as results including the Country that was attached to the Basket, which it shouldn't.

The problem seems to be that the '!=' in the closure seems to be not working.

If I would just query with only `whereHas()` I can get the result if I want the Country with a relation with Basket with id 1, but not all Countries with relations with Baskets BUT id 1, as it wouldn't exclude it and basically ignore the `where()` in the closure;

```
$countries = Country::wherehas('baskets', function($query) {
            $query->where('id', 1); // This works, but not the opposite by adding the `!=` operator
        })->get()
```

What am doing wrong? I've got this code working perfectly fine for many-to-many relations (using something like `basket_id` instead for the `where()` statement).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you really want is *"get all Countries where there doesn't exist any Basket with both my country_id and id=1"*.

**So, the solution is:**

```php
$countries = Country::whereDoesntHave('baskets', function($query) {
    $query->where('baskets.id', '=', 1);
})->get();
```

which, if you test with the `->toSql()` (instead of `->get()`) gives you

```sql
select * from `countries`
where not exists
  (select * from `baskets` where `countries`.`id` = `baskets`.`country_id` and `id` = 1)
```

**Why didn't your original query work?**

```
$countries = Country::whereDoesntHave('baskets')
        ->orWherehas('baskets', function($query) {
            $query->where('id', '!=', 1);
        })->get();
```

would return something like

```sql
select * from `countries`
where not exists
  (select * from `baskets`
   where `countries`.`id` = `baskets`.`country_id`)
or exists
  (select * from `baskets`
   where `countries`.`id` = `baskets`.`country_id` and `baskets`.`id` != 1)
```

So the `orWhereHas` gets translated to *"or where there exists at least one Basket that has my country_id but whose id is not 1"*. This is not what you wanted.

For example: if a Country has, say, two Baskets, one with id=1 and the other with id=100, the latter Basket satisfies that second "exists" clause of your query, and that Country would therefore be included in your results. In other words, there *does exist* a Basket belonging to that country that doesn't have id=1.

**Bonus solution:** ()

A much simpler solution arises if you happen to already have that particular Basket loaded (or you don't mind making a second call to the db). Since this is one-to-many, a given Basket can only belong to one Country, and so another way of phrasing the query is *"get all Countries whose id is not that Basket's country_id"*

```php
$bad_basket = Basket::find(1);
$countries = Country::where('id', '!=', $bad_basket->country_id);
```

Comment: Thanks! Somehow I never thought of simply putting a closure into whereDoesntHave() >_<